# Generate an id in the td of a row, from the Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table where I need to fill an ID in a td using the value retrieved from a Mysql Table. I tried like this:

```
<?php 
   $ww = db_query("SELECT id, item1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = '".$record->main_data."'" );
?>  
<td id="id_field1" class="<?php echo $ww->id;?>" >
    <?php
        foreach($ww as $ee)
            { echo $ee->item1;}
    ?>
</td>
```

I know the use of:

```
  <td id="id_field1" class="<?php echo $ww->id;?>" >
```

is wrong, but I am not getting any other idea can you help me **to generate an id for this td from the id retrieved from the Query**?

**EDIT**

After the use of:

```
$ww = db_query("SELECT id, item1, FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = '" . $record->main_data . "'");
 foreach ($ww as $row) {
?>
<td id="id_field<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" >
    <?php echo $row->item1; ?>
</td>
<?php
```

}

I am getting two issues--

**1 )**  Getting a warning from the DATATABLES plugin for fixedheader which says

```
Requesetd unknown parameter '11' for row 0
```

**2 )**  For empty td , the next  `<td>` gets moved , instead of first `<td>` and I am getting the second `<td>` values of class and id inside the first... In this case, the table row is shifted to left with empty in the last column td

### EDIT2 : this worked with no issues

I tried like this - is it ok to do like this: please comment on it-

```
     <?php $ww = db_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = '".$record->main_data."'" );?>
    <td id="id_field1" class="cart_wonid<?php foreach($ww as $ee) { echo $ee->id;}?>">
        <?php 
            $ww = db_query("SELECT item1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = '".$record->main_data."'" );
            foreach($ww as $ee){
                echo $ee->main_data;
            }
        ?>
    </td>
```

Comment: Remove the last comma in `id, item1,` <= *right there*. If that's part of your actual code, MySQL should have thrown you an error had you been checking for them.

Comment: thanks... but can u solve this issue @Fred

Comment: See the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

OP using drupal.

Put your `td` into the loop.

```
$ww = db_query("SELECT id, item1, FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = '" . $record->main_data . "'");
foreach ($ww as $row) {
    ?>
    <td id="id_field<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" >
        <?php echo $row->item1; ?>
    </td>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I removed the trailing comma, you added it back in. Syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, I just moved the td into the loop. Now I've removed the comma from query.

Comment: OP removed the comma from the question after they saw my  comment. I re-edited yours. But thanks for the mention anyway. ;-)

Comment: but error it says  `: Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_fetch_assoc() in `

Comment: @user___ You also need to let us know which API you're using to connect with. You have a custom query function, so the variable for connection will need to be inserted in the `while` loop and using the fetching method of the given MySQL API. `mysql_` - `mysqli_` - PDO?

Comment: but a warning is coming and the id and class is showing the same value at the **td**. this time `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in include()`

Comment: Please show, what if you says `var_dump($ww)` after you `db_query`. You are using some framework, or some custom db handler functions. What is that?

Comment: @lolka_bolka : can u guide me to get through this problem &  iam using the Drupal framework.

Comment: when i tried the var_dump($ww) ; iam getting a very huge data... like a loop executed 20 or more times

Comment: @lolka_bolka : iam getting expected data in the class field... but again - two issues ---**1** Getting a warning from the DATATABLES plugin for fixedheader which says  `Requesetd unknown parameter '11' for row 0.` ----**2** for empty td the class and the id is filled with the same data..

Comment: ----**2** this issue is the <td> gets moved , instead of first <td> iam getting the second <td>... please help me in solving this....